# Como permitir apenas uma instancia de um programa feito em Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Supondo que criei um programa em Python e ele está funcionando perfeitamente, como fazer para permitir apenas uma instancia do programa por vez? Pesquisei no Google e encontrei uma pessoa dizendo ter resolvido a questão usando PID's, mas não era em Python e não havia mais detalhes, também não encontrei informações sobre a solução citada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Forma 1

Salve um arquivo em algum lugar, e pode verificar se o processo está rodando caso o pid já exista no arquivo. Note, que precisar-se-á de deletar o arquivo após terminar a execução.

Salve o [ID do processo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_de_processo)  em um arquivo temporário. E coloque para verificar se esse arquivo existe no início do programa além de apagar o arquivo quando o processo for encerrado.

```
import os
import sys

pid = str(os.getpid())
pidfile = "/tmp/mydaemon.pid"

if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
    print ("Processo já existe e não será executado novamente")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    #seu programa aqui
    facaAlgo()
os.unlink(pidfile)
```

## Forma 2

Ao utilizar tendo

```
from tendo import singleton
me = singleton.SingleInstance() # roda sys.exit(-1) se existe outra instância.
```

**Como instalar o a biblioteca Tendo:**

```
easy_install tendo
pip install tendo
manualmente pelo site: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tendo
```

Comment: como executa uma aplicação utilizando esta forma de singleton??

Comment: @britodfbr quer dizer por meio da biblioteca ou usando o PID?